# Want to solve $\int \frac{\sqrt{t}}{1-2t}dt$ by substitution using only $t = \frac{1}{2}\cos^2\theta$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I used substituition as required to solve this: Let $t = \frac{1}{2}\cos^2\theta$
where $0 \leq \theta \leq \frac\pi2$.

So I want to solve $$\int \dfrac{\sqrt{t}}{1-2t}dt$$ By substituition, we have this form $$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int\csc\theta - \sin\theta ~d\theta$$

The end result is $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left[-\ln\left|\csc\theta+\cot\theta\right| + \cos\theta + C\right]$$

Now I have some trouble subbing in $\theta = \cos^{-1}\sqrt{2t}$ back to the equation.

Comment: You have $\cos(\theta) = \sqrt{2t}$, and so $\sin(\theta) = \sqrt{1 - 2t}$.

Comment: $\cos x$ have its inverse on $0<x<\pi$, therefore $\sin x$ is positive.  Hence you can put $\sin \theta=\sqrt{1-2 t}$ into your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Let $\sqrt t=v\implies t=v^2,dt=2v\ dv$

$$\int\dfrac{\sqrt t\ dt}{1-2t}=\int\dfrac{2v^2\ dv}{1-2v^2}$$

$$=\int\dfrac{(2v^2-1+1)\ dv}{1-2v^2}=\dfrac12\int\dfrac{dv}{(1/\sqrt2)^2-v^2}-\int dv$$

Comment: appreciated, however the question only wants us to use their substitution.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int {\sqrt{t}\over 1-2t}dt\tag1$$

$t={1\over 2}\cos^2 \theta\tag a$

$\sqrt{t}={\sqrt{2}\over 2}\cos \theta \tag b$

$1-2t=1-\cos^2 \theta=\sin^2 \theta \tag c$

${dt\over d\theta}=-\sin\theta \cos\theta\tag d$

$$-{\sqrt{2}\over 2}\int {\cos^2 \theta\over \sin \theta }d\theta \tag2$$

Standard integral formula sheet:

> $$\int {\cos^2 a\theta\over \sin a\theta}d \theta={\cos a\theta\over a}+{1\over a}\ln \tan{a\theta \over 2}\tag3$$

setting $a=1$

$$-{\sqrt{2}\over 2}\int {\cos^2 \theta\over \sin \theta }d\theta=\cos \theta+\ln\tan {\theta \over 2} \tag4$$

$\tan {\theta \over 2}={1-\cos \theta \over \sin \theta}={\sin \theta\over 1+\cos\theta }\tag5$

$$\int {\sqrt{t}\over 1-2t}dt=-\sqrt{t}+{\sqrt{2}\over 2}\ln\left( \sqrt{1-2t}\over {1-\sqrt{2t}}\right)+c\tag6$$